# Kdb - string to double or float

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I am trying to convert a string into a double or a float in KDB - the string contains a number with "accounting" format of the like of `2,228,25` (amount) - is I use something like `"j"$amount` I get `50 44 50 50 56 46 50 53` as a return value. How do I convert that string into a proper number? Thanks

Answer (score 8):

When casting strings to atoms of other types in kdb+, you must use capital letters to cast. Casting a string with commas to a number will return null values, so try removing them using either except or ssr.

```
"J"$"2,228,25" except ","
```

or

```
"J"$ssr["2,228,25";",";""]
```

Comment: Thank you very very much - your comment works for the example provided. I had a small typo and the string is 2,228.25 . For whatever reason when I run your command with 2,229.25 I get 0N. not sure. Thank you again

Comment: The above example was for converting your string to a long. The null return is being caused by the decimal point. Case with "F" or "E" instead.

Answer (score 2):

As the other example stated you can use `except` to exclude "," before converting. However, if you have many characters in the string that you need to remove, and those vary, you can use `inter` and a list of accepted characters rather than have exceptions:

```
q)amt:"2/228,25.0"
q)"F"$amt inter "0123456789."
222825f
```